# display:none added to html in FF works fine in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a website http://jazztravels.com. In my site, the home page has images loaded from my custom post, However the images does not seem to load in FF while it works perfectly fine in IE.

I noticed that display:none is added to the image tag, which is not present in IE. However I am unable to identify why this is added and how it can be avoided.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the images are not loading in chrome 12 either. fyi; and my FF shows the image, two of them, one below the other. css mess up.

Comment: The images are hidden in IE 9 also, and the menu doesn't display properly there either.

Comment: I've not figured out exactly why, but the problem lies with the coin-slider script. Incidentally it doesn't work in IE9 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems, that you have spaces(' ') in your path names. You should remove them, as FF and IE handle them differently.

In FF I see a request for: http://jazztravels.com/wp-content/themes/Doubtfire%20Wordpress%20Theme/css/colour/images/shine.png

Comment: The images are requested eventhough they are hidden. The `%20` is the correct encoding for a space, so Fx does some sanitizing before using the URL. This does however not explain why the images are hidden.

Comment: Hi nfechner,
Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I removed the extra spaces in the file path and it seems to be working fine in FF too. Dunno about Chrome and IE9. It would be great if somebody can check and let me know.